# How to handle categorical variable with smotefamily in R?

Tags: r, oversampling

I'm having some problem with smotefamily package in R.

When I'm dealing with categorical variable with the SMOTE families(SMOTE, Borderline SMOTE and others), it is not possible to generate synthetic examples cause they use the distance between minority class sample and its nearest neighbors. 
However, when I used SMOTE in DMwR package, it was do possible to use categorical variables. What is the difference and how can I use categorical variables with SMOTE family? 
I don't want the value of the variable(the variables are "monitoring station number" and "month", each.) to be numeric(like 10.58811~~) but to be categorical or at least to be integer.